# Starting Mongo Query router on system reboot

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have a sharded MongoDB cluster setup running under a single `mongos` instance. I have added another `mongos` instance which runs fine with existing configuration.

**Problem**: I want the two `mongos` instances to be automatically started when the system reboots.

So far I have created a bash script to start the server and added a crontab entry which supposed to run this bash script at the system startup. But the script is no longer executed by crontab. No log entries or no any errors.

Why is the script not running by CRON? When I manually run the script using `bash`command, it runs fine and starts the server without any problem.

The script looks like below:

```
#!/bin/bash
mongos  --configdb "config0:27020,config1:27020,config2:27020" --port "27017" --logpath "/data/mongodb.log" &
```

And the crontab entry is:

```
@reboot /startMongos.sh
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do this with cron? There are other tools for this like for example Upstart for Ubuntu...

Comment: @mgsk Any better option for this?

Comment: What system are you on?

Comment: @mgsk I don't know how to use Upstart for `mongos`. Do you have any idea for that? Any links? 
The system is Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: _You can use the mongod init script to derive your own mongos control script._ Google around, start here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#control-scripts . **Don't do this with cron.**